# Fundamental groups of Hirzebruch's line arrangement varities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-surfaces, fundamental-group

Let $\Lambda$ be a line arrangement in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $n > 0$ an integer. Then [Hirzebruch defined](https://hirzebruch.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/id/eprint/244/1/hirzebrucharr.pdf) a smooth projective surface $H(\Lambda, n)$ as the minimal desingularization of a covering $Y \to \mathbb{P}^2$ branched over $\Lambda$ defined by the function field,

$$ \mathbb{C}(\mathbb{P}^2)( (\ell_1/\ell_k)^{1/n}, \cdots, (\ell_{k-1}/\ell_k)^{1/n}) $$
where $\ell_1, \dots, \ell_k$ are linear forms defining the $k$ lines of $\Lambda$.

I am wondering if the fundamental group of $H(\Lambda, n)$ has been studied in terms of the arrangement $\Lambda$. In particular, have the $\Lambda$ such that $\pi_1(H(\Lambda, n)) = 0$ (or finite is also interesting) been classified?

I know that both K3 surfaces and $K(\pi, 1)$ general type surfaces appear as examples so the answer to this question may be quite complicated.

Also, does anyone know a reference that computes the Hodge numbers of $H(\Lambda, n)$?